# Modifying a browser for the Sahara desert

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I'm modifying a browser (Chrome or Firefox) to work in the Sahara desert - or any environment with very poor connectivity.  I can configure the browser, recompile it, or even insert a custom coded proxy.  The goal is to make it operate well with spotty, slow connectivity.

I've found the biggest problem to be that even when you get the main page, the browser will often hang, waiting for the CSS and JS etc to load.  How can I force the browser to "Render the page right away, don't worry about other resources?"

Comment: You have not shown any code. StackOverflow is about specific programming, not generalized "how-to" questions.  If you're going to recompile a new browser, then just rewrite it to do whatever you require; what are you asking us?  What do you mean by "good generic CSS"?  Every browser has some basic CSS rules built into it, and there's no such thing as "generic CSS" that will know how to properly render any website when the specific rules fail to load.  If there was, then we wouldn't need to write any rules for each website.

Comment: **Opera Mini** will render pages server-side, transfer as few bytes as possible and render page client-side with a few possible interactions. It has huge marketshare where connectivity is flaky. Otherwise you could cache main JS libraries found on Google, Yahoo and MS or use Normalize on top of existing UA stylesheets but there's nothing universal with that. I'd rather desactivate JS and/or images and/or CSS, etc (I use QuickJava extension on Fx, goes far beyond Java). Also Firefox is superior to other browsers when it comes to displaying `alt` content in lieu of images

Comment: Bootstrap is the absolute *worst* framework to use in a situation involving spotty Internet connectivity.

Comment: @Sparky - I have to disagree, good design has to come before you start coding!

Comment: Disagree all you want… your question still doesn't fit [the posting guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Presumably if you have access to the browser source code, then you modify that to ignore dependencies.  However, the real question for you is: what sites are they browsing?  Because a large number of them won't work without those dependencies which include javascript frameworks, css files, images, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page isn't waiting for the resources to render, browsers generally always render HTML as soon as they have it available.  However, the CSS and JS files are likely being sent before the generic HTML for the page, as web designers don't generally like their page to go through multi-step formatting processes while the CSS page loads in, nor do most users. You're likely getting almost none of the HTML until after the CSS or JS loads. Presumably, if you have full control of the browser's functionality, you may be able to tell it to skip these or save the address to load in later? I wouldn't recommend this behavior though, as it could break a lot of functionality, especially with JS.

If images are missing, they should show the alt text. If they're loading, they may not. Again, with full control of the browser, I don't see why this should be a problem for you.

There is no 'generic' CSS. CSS rules are largely customized based on classes and identities defined by the author. More modern webpages which make use of newer HTML5 elements have more semantic information available to guide display without a stylesheet. Short of this, you need the accompanying stylesheet for proper display. You could attempt to guess or reengineer, but the vast majority of the time this will fail, as there was little to no convention prior to HTML5 bringing in more semantic elements.

Comment: Most browser won't show the alt text if it doesn't fit in the image's box.  I need something to style it appropriately to fit inside the box.

Comment: Then to help you, we need to know what _something_ is. Do you have source code? Are you writing extensions? Do you know if you _can_ make this change with what you have available? If so, have you identified where changes would need to be made? If so, have you attempted to make the changes? If so, what have you attempted? Without this information, you're asking for directions from people without telling them where you're at. We need to know what you have and what you've tried before we can help you get where you want to be.

Comment: Um.  There's quite a bit of fail in this answer.  The generic HTML ALWAYS comes first as parsing that is how the browser knows what else it's supposed to get.  A page will not render until the browser has enough information to start putting things where it needs to go.  For example, if you have a Table tag and the columns are using % widths then the browser will wait until the entire table is loaded before it renders.  Alt Text shows if the image can't be loaded, it's not shown if the browser is trying to load it.  Now, your

Comment: Now, your third paragraph is accurate.

Comment: Allow me to clarify my meaning, my wording may have bit a bit ambiguous/inconsistent. I'm referring to parsing and what you see as a viewer. Obviously, the primary file has to be downloaded fully first, but when the parser hits a CSS object in the head element, unoptimized CSS will be parsed before displaying HTML elements (to avoid FOUC). Further, JS files will halt document parsing until they are completed unless explicitly told not to with the defer attribute. As for alt text, what you said is exactly what I had meant.